# Apply echo and pitch changes to audio file on Android using Superpowered

Tags: android, audio

In a android project im working on, there is a option for the user to record a audio file and send it to another user.
After the user records it, i want the option of adding an effect of "echo" or a pitch change, and send the new audio file created with one of those effects.

I want to know if this is possible using [Supowerpowered](http://superpowered.com/) and if so, i would like some example, sample or pointers on how to do so.

**Edit**: I also dont mind using an alternative library if there is any.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible using Superpowered. Please find the SuperpoweredOfflineProcessingExample project in the SDK, and open ViewController.mm.

https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/blob/master/SuperpoweredOfflineProcessingExample/SuperpoweredOfflineProcessingExample/ViewController.mm

The offlineFilter method shows how to apply an effect on an audio file and save the result. The SuperpoweredEcho is very similar to the SuperpoweredFilter, just replace filter with the echo.

Comment: i am not able run code for android CrossExample ,  the issue SuperpoweredExample.h (JNI folder)